# Subobjects and quotient objects in category of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Are the following definitions are equivalent?

> An embedding of topological spaces is just a monic in **Top**, i.e. it is a continuous $e: A \rightarrow X$ s.t. for any space $Z$ the function $f \mapsto e \circ f:$ **Top** $\left(Z,A\right)\rightarrow$ **Top** $\left(Z,X\right)$ is injective i.e. $e_\circ f_1=e\circ f_2 \implies f_1 =f_2$.

and

> $e:A \rightarrow X$ is an embedding iff
>
> - $U\left(e\right):U\left(A\right)\rightarrow U\left(X\right)$ is injective in **Set**, where $U$ is the underling set functor.
> - for any $Z \in$ **Top** a set map  $U\left(f\right):U\left(Z\right) \rightarrow U\left(A\right)$, $f$ is continues iff $e \circ f : Z \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

Is the analogue definitions for epic and quotient space are also equivalent? Many thanks.

Comment: No. An embedding of topological spaces is - by definition - something stronger: A continuous map which is injective and induces a homeomorphism onto its image.

Answer (score 12):

Let **Top** be the category of topological spaces (and continuous maps) and **Haus** be the subcategory of Hausdorff topological spaces.

- [monomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism) in **Top** and **Haus** are precisely injective continuous maps;
- epimorphisms in **Top** are precisely surjective continuous maps;
- epimorphisms in **Haus** are precisely dense continuous maps (i.e., maps $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $\overline{f[X]}=Y$); see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214045/what-are-the-epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-hausdorff-spaces).

Note that not every monomorphism is an embedding. Not every epimorphisms is a quotient map.

Your second description says that $A$ has the [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) w.r.t. to the map $e$. This is the same as saying that $e$ is an embedding. Similarly, final topology corresponds to a quotient map.

It might be also useful to mention that in **Top** the [extremal monomophisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_monomorphism) and regular monomorphisms coincide with embeddings. In **Haus** we get closed embeddings. Regular and extremal epimorphisms are quotient maps in both **Top** and **Haus**.

Answer (score 3):

The first definition actually characterises *injective continuous maps*, but the second definition does indeed characterise topological embeddings. More generally there is a notion of initial topology and final topology for a family of maps, and an embedding is precisely an injective map that induces the initial topology on its domain, and a quotient is precisely a surjective map that induces the final topology on its codomain. The universal property you have written down is a translation of that into the language of category theory.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the notion of an extremal monic in a category. This is a monic $m$ such that for each factorization $m=f\circ e$ where $e$ is an epic, $e$ is also an isomorphism.

Using this notion, one can characterize the topological embeddings categorically: They are just the extremal monics in **Top**.

Dually, an extremal epic is an extremal monic in the opposite category. Specifically, it is an epic $e$ such that each monic $m$ in a factorization $e=m\circ f$ is an isomorphism.

The extremal epics in **Top** are precisely the quotient maps.