# Non-injective monomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I am reading Borceux, vol. 1, I found this example at page 27:

we consider the category whose object are the pairs $\langle X,x\rangle$ where $X$ is a topological space and $x$ a point of $X$ (base point). In this category, a morphism $f:\langle X,x\rangle\longrightarrow\langle Y,y\rangle$ is a continuous mapping $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ which preserves base points. Let us consider the projection $\pi$ of the circular helix $\mathcal{H}$ on the circle $\mathcal{S}^1$,
$$\pi:\langle \mathcal{H},h\rangle\longrightarrow\langle\mathcal{S}^1,s\rangle$$

with $h\in\mathcal{H}$ and $s=\pi(h)$. If $f:\langle X,x\rangle\longrightarrow\langle\mathcal{S}^1,s\rangle$ is a morphism in our category which admits a lifting
$$g:\langle X,x\rangle\longrightarrow\langle\mathcal{H},h\rangle$$
through the projection $\pi$, that lifting is necessarily unique (see Spanier, pag 67), and so $\pi$ is a (non-injective) monomorphism...

This is pretty clear to me, except for a single detail: why do we need to consider base points (and morphisms preserving them)? Is there a problem if we simply consider the category $\operatorname{\mathbf{Top}}$ of topological spaces and continuous mappings?

Comment: Liftings are made with a choice of base point, hence it is natural to point spaces in order to do so. In the category of topological spaces without base points, you can choose liftings with different base point, and hence your map won't be a monomorphism. In fact, two lifts over a connected total space that are different at a point differ everywhere. To be more succinct: unique lifting is always regarding a (fixed) basepoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borceux's example is incorrect. Here is a general observation.

> Let $(C, U : C \to \text{Set})$ be a concrete category such that the forgetful functor $U$ to sets has a left adjoint. Then monomorphisms are injective (meaning that $U$ preserves monomorphisms).

This covers most familiar examples of concrete categories, including topological spaces, groups, rings, etc. In particular, it includes based topological spaces! Here the left adjoint takes a set $X$ to the pointed space given by $X$ with the discrete topology plus a new basepoint.

You can use this to show that Borceux's map, which amounts to the exponential map $\exp : (\mathbb{R}, 0) \to (S^1, 1)$, is not a monomorphism. If we let $2 = 1 + 1$ be a point and a basepoint, then the map $2 \to S^1$ sending everything to the basepoint has many lifts, given by sending the non-basepoint to any lift of the basepoint in $\mathbb{R}$.

This example can be fixed by restricting further to the category of path connected (and maybe locally path connected, to be on the safe side) based spaces; in this category any [covering map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) is a monomorphism because unique lifting actually holds here. Here the forgetful functor no longer has a left adjoint, so the above no longer applies.

Comment: I've noticed on at least one other occasion that Borceux gets sloppy when discussing examples (here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214045/what-are-the-epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-hausdorff-spaces), so be on the lookout for that in general.