# Quotient space in topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

In this thread: 
[What are the epimorphisms in the category of Hausdorff spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214045/what-are-the-epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-hausdorff-spaces?rq=1)

the quotient space of a topological space $X$ by a closed set $A \subset X$ is mentioned : $X / A$. This confused me, because I thought you can only quotient by an equivalence relation. In groups, I know that this equivalence relation for $G/H$ is implicitly given by $a \sim b$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$. But in topological spaces we don't have products and inverses, so my question is, what does this space mean? In particular, can someone tell me explicitly when $x \sim y$ (or $\overline{x} = \overline{y}$) in the space $X/A$? The only thing I can think of is: 
$$
\overline{x} = \overline{y} \ \Leftrightarrow x \in A, y \in A, 
$$
but I'm not sure if this is correct, it seems like a strange definition to me.

Comment: The relation is "identify all points in $A$ together, all other points are identified with themselves."

Comment: The most natural IMHO is to describe the set of equivalence classes as $\{\{x\}: x \notin A\} \cup \{A\}$, so we" identify $A$ to a point", as it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x\sim y\iff x=y\text{ or }x\text{ and }y\text{ are both elements of subset }A$$

Comment: Thanks. So basically the entire subset $A$ becomes one point in the quotient space, and all other points remain the same right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: But you must also get the topology right.