# In the category Haus, a continuous map $f:A \rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism iff $f(A)$ is dense in $B$

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

I am just getting started with category theory and I am trying to prove that

> **In the category Haus, a continuous map $f:A \rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism iff $f(A)$ is dense in $B$**

I found a partial answer here

[What are the epimorphisms in the category of Hausdorff spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214045/what-are-the-epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-hausdorff-spaces/214049#214049)

The proof of  "$f(A)$ is dense in $B \implies f$ is an epimorphism" is missing. They only prove the converse I think, which I don't fully understand.

**My questions  are**

**1) How do I prove this  "$f(A)$ is dense in $B \implies f$ is an epimorphism"?**

**2) About the proof of the converse which I paste here:**
[image]

-**What is the idea of the proof? How does taking the topological union of two copies of B and the "natural maps" does the trick?** **I am not sure I understand what a "topological union is", how is it anydifferent from a normal union?** By the way, I guess by natural maps they mean this

[image]   (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_map)

-**Regarding the highlighted part, could you give more details?** Specifically I don't understand how to check that  $h \circ f=k\circ f$. Then by the epimorphism property we get $h=k$, how do they conclude that $f[A]$ is dense in $B$? And isn't one more step missing, i.e. showing that $f(A)$ is dense in $B $?

Comment: **1)** Suppose $h \circ f = k \circ f$. This means that  $f(A) \subseteq \{y \in B : h(y)=k(y)\}$. Now, if $f(A)$ is dense in $B$, what does this implies?

Comment: @azif00 $h\circ f=k\circ f$ just means $h(f(x))=k(f(x)) \forall x \in$ dom $f$. I don't understand where that inclusion comes from

Comment: @azif00 Secondly, $f(A)$ dense in $B$, implies $B=\overline {(f(A))}=\overline{\{y \in B h(y)=k(y) \}}$, what is next?

Comment: @some_math_guy: $C=q[B_0\sqcup B_1]$, and in this case $B_0\sqcup B_1$ is simply $B\times\{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. The two natural maps from $B$ to $C$ are $h:B\to C:x\mapsto q(\langle x,0\rangle)$ and $k:B\to C:x\mapsto q(\langle x,1\rangle)$. If $x\in A$, then $f(x)\in f[A]$, so the points $\langle f(x),0\rangle$ and $\langle f(x),1\rangle$ have been identified, and therefore $$h\big(f(x)\big)=q(\langle f(x),0\rangle)=q(\langle f(x),1\rangle)=k\big(f(x)\big)\,.$$ And $x\in A$ was arbitrary, so $h\circ f=k\circ f$. It’s a standard fact that continuous functions …

Comment: … from a space $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$ that agree on a dense subset of $X$ are equal; this is straightforward to prove, and I see now that **diracdeltafunk**’s answer includes a proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Morphisms with dense image are epic" is basically another way to say that "if two continuous functions agree on a dense set then they are equal". Actually, let's prove this as a lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $f, g : X \to Y$ be continuous functions, where $Y$ is Hausdorff. If $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g) := \{x \in X : f(x) = g(x)\}$ is dense in $X$, then $f = g$.

*Proof.* $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$ is the inverse image of $\Delta_Y \subseteq Y \times Y$ under the continuous map $(f,g) : X \to Y \times Y$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, $\Delta_Y$ is closed in $Y \times Y$, so by continuity of $(f,g)$ we have that $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$ is closed in $X$. If $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$ is dense in $X$, we then conclude that $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g) = X$, i.e. $f = g$. $\square$

Now the claim follows easily:

**Proposition.** Let $h : X \to Y$ be a morphism in $\mathsf{Haus}$ such that $h(X)$ is dense in $Y$. Then $h$ is an epimorphism.

*Proof.* Let $f,g : Y \to Z$ be morphisms in $\mathsf{Haus}$ such that $f \circ h = g \circ h$. Then $f(y) = g(y)$ for all $y \in h(X)$, i.e. $h(X) \subseteq \operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$. Since $h(X)$ is dense in $Y$, $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$ is dense in $Y$. Since $Z$ is Hausdorff, we apply the lemma to conclude that $f = g$. $\square$

---

Your understanding of the phrase "natural map" is not correct. Here, "disjoint topological union" refers to the coproduct in $\mathsf{Top}$. Given two spaces $A$ and $B$, we may form a space $A \amalg B$, whose underlying set is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, and whose open sets are precisely the pairwise disjoint unions of open subsets of $A$ and $B$.

Pictorally, $A \amalg B$ is the topological space which consists of both $A$ and $B$ -- for example, $S^1$ is a circle, and $S^1 \amalg S^1$ is two (disjoint) circles. People will say "natural maps" in this context to refer to the inclusions of $A$ and $B$ into $A \amalg B$.

But the construction in this proof is actually slightly more involved than the coproduct -- it is an amalgamated coproduct. This is where "... corresponding points of the closure of $f[A]$ have been identified" comes in. Here's the whole proof:

**Proposition.** Let $f : A \to B$ be an epimorphism in $\mathsf{Haus}$. Then $f(A)$ is dense in $B$.

*Proof.* We begin with an epimorphism $f : A \to B$. Then we form the space $B \amalg B$, which comes with two natural maps $i_1, i_2 : B \to B \amalg B$. Next, we form the quotient $(B \amalg B)/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $i_1(b) \sim i_2(b)$ for all $b \in \overline{f(A)}$. This comes with a natural map (of the kind referenced in your screenshot) $\pi : B \amalg B \to (B \amalg B)/{\sim}$. Now we check that $(B \amalg B)/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff, by noting that $${\sim} = \Delta_{B \amalg B} \cup \operatorname{img}((i_1,i_2) : \overline{f(A)} \to (B \amalg B)^2) \cup \operatorname{img}((i_2,i_1) : \overline{f(A)} \to (B \amalg B)^2)$$ is a closed subset of $(B \amalg B)^2$. Finally, we have that
$$(\pi \circ i_1) \circ f = \pi \circ (i_1 \circ f) = \pi \circ (i_2 \circ f) = (\pi \circ i_2) \circ f$$
by construction. Since $f$ is epic by assumption we conclude that $\pi \circ i_1 = \pi \circ i_2$. However, $\pi(i_1(b)) \neq \pi(i_2(b))$ for any $b \in B \setminus \overline{f(A)}$, and so we conclude that $B \setminus \overline{f(A)} = \varnothing$, i.e. $\overline{f(A)} = B$. In other words, $f(A)$ is dense in $B$. $\square$

Comment: what do you mean by "epic" in the first line?

Comment: "epic" is the adjective form of "epimorphism". "$f$ is epic" means the same thing as "$f$ is an epimorphism". "Epic" is also synonymous with "epimorphic".

Comment: what is $\Delta_Y$? It's not defined anywhere

Comment: $\Delta_Y = \{(y,y) : y \in Y\}$. This is sometimes called the "diagonal of $Y$". It is an important fact of point-set topology that a space $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\Delta_Y$ is closed in $Y \times Y$.

Comment: 1) In the proof of the lemma or the first proposition, don't I need X to be Hausdorf?.  Since we are in the Haus category for the proposition later, would it be a valid proof of the lemma to observe that $Eq(f,g)=h^{-1}(\{x\})$, with $h=f-g$ a continuous function, is a closed set in $X$ because it is the preimage of a singleton set in a Haussdorff top space (singletons are always closed in Hausdorff spaces). ?

Comment: 2) Could you elaborate a bit on why  "$${\sim} = \Delta_{B \amalg B} \cup \operatorname{img}((i_1,i_2) : B \to (B \amalg B)^2)$$ is a closed subset of $(B \amalg B)^2$" ?

Comment: 1) No, $X$ does not need to be Hausdorff for this to hold. You can see that I never assumed that $X$ is Hausdorff in the proof, so if you think this should be necessary then you would need to also point out an invalid step in the proof!

And no, $f-g$ does not even make sense in general. This *would* make sense if the codomain of $f$ and $g$ was $\mathbb{R}$, or something like that, but we have no such assumption.

Comment: I did not think X Hausdorf was necessary in the lemma, I just thought I could use it to make a different proof. But you are right f-g does not make sense.

Comment: 3) why is $i_1\circ f = i_2 \circ f$ ? I read in the wikipedia page that on disjoint union https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union  that elements in the disjoint union are denoted with an index $(x,i)$ to keep track of what set they come from. So  it looks like the elements in the image of $i_1$ have index 1 and that those  of $i_2$ have index 2, therefore I can't say the maps are the same because the images are not the same? if I am not mistaken $i_1: x \in B \mapsto (x,1)$ while  $i_2: x \in B \mapsto (x,2)$ is how we defined them.

Comment: 4) why is $\pi(i_1(b)) \neq \pi(i_2(b))$ for any $b \in B \setminus \overline{f(A)}$?

Comment: 2) Since $B$ is Hausdorff, $B \amalg B$ is Hausdorff, so $\Delta_{B \amalg B}$ is closed in $(B \amalg B)^2$. A union of two closed sets is closed, so it suffices now to show that the image of $(i_1, i_2)$ is closed. Note that $(B \amalg B)^2$ is homeomorphic to 4 copies of $B \times B$. In fact, $(i_1, i_2)$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, identifying $B$ with a copy of $\Delta_B$ in one of these copies of $B \times B$. In particular, $(i_1, i_2)$ has closed image. I will leave the task of writing out the details to you.

Comment: 3) $i_1 \circ f$ is not equal to $i_2 \circ f$, but $\pi \circ (i_1 \circ f) = \pi \circ (i_2 \circ f)$ because $i_1(f(a)) \sim i_2(f(a))$ for all $a \in A$ by construction.

Comment: 4) $i_1(b)$ and $i_2(b)$ are not related by $\sim$ whenever $b \notin \overline{f(A)}$.

Comment: If they are not related, can I argue that they are different precisely because they one of them is actually (b,1) and the other (b,2)? with distinct indeces, which i think is the reason why taking a disjoint union was useful. I noticed you don't use the indeces, can't that lead to mixing the elements up? I needed the indeces to notice this last thing(provided it is correct how I am seeing it)

Comment: Thanks for everything, your explanation was very clear

Comment: One last thing how do we know $i_1$ and $i_2$ are continuous? I thing we need it to argue that $(i_1 \circ f)$ and $(i_2\circ f)$ are continuous

Comment: When you show that $(B \amalg B) / \sim$ is Hausdorff, aren't you using that $\overline{f(A)} = B$? I mean, is the proof still valid if we take the sets $img((i_1, i_2): \overline{f(A)} \to (B \amalg B)^2)$?

Comment: @BlueTomato Quotients of Hausdorff spaces are not always Hausdorff. But thank you, I had a typo! I did mean $(i_1, i_2) : \overline{f(A)} \to (B \amalg B)^2$. Then we only use that $\overline{f(A)}$ is closed in $B$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks to you, since your proofs are fully understandable. It is crucial to continually observe that we are still working with objects and morphisms in our category.